# Calendar week_of_year comes week_of_month

Tags: java, calendar

I am retrieving the number of week in the year from a date but it seems it returns me the number of week in the month.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        cal.setTime((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")).parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int num_of_week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

I input "2014-08-18" and it comes out 3 as result.......how can I correctly retrieve the week number.......

Comment: check what `mm` does.

Comment: Opps, silly problem. Thx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cal.setTime((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse(date));
                                        ^^---Change the month to MM
```

instead of

```
cal.setTime((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")).parse(date));
```